# How to exclude specific file/s from being Cached in Chrome. (like js files)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, caching

We are currently developing a website. And every time we edit "user.js" file and to see our updates we need to hard refresh the page which will cause a longer loading time because it will load all the JS, CSS and IMG again from the server. It took more than five seconds of waiting.

I can't totally disable caching so the pages will much faster 1-3 seconds.

My goal now is to know how to disable cache on specific file or files so the rest of the CSS,JS, and IMG files stays cached.

This will give us effeciency in coding.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50277036

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can use this but i hope that there is a way that i can specifically exclude it temporarily on chrome because i also wanted it to stay cache if i am not developing yet.

Comment: Personally I would do it on the server side by checking the server url and disable cache for localhost. If that's not possible, maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736881/760331

Comment: I see, i really appreciated it, i would now be utilizing the first option you gave it is more easier than the second one,

Thanks alot for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome cache removal for single files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881027/chrome-cache-removal-for-single-files)

Comment: below already answer my question. If I want a file to hard refresh i just need to open that specific file on a tab and hard refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific concern, this is what i do.

If you wanted to hard refresh this file every time you edit it, and without hard refreshing the whole page.

**You just need to hard refresh that specific file**

`https://xdxd.com/user.js`

Then **open your page normally on new tab**, and must be in new tab so the changes will apply.

That's the trick i am doing. If ever i dont want to Hard Refresh the whole website.